# Could the forward function of torch.nn pass the learnable parameters and update it?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, parameters, neural-network, gradient-descent

I have write two torch.nn modules, and I want pass some learnable parameters between them. I know this may not be the norm, but could this lead to some training errors or parameter updating error?

An toy example is shown in below:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class SubModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubModel, self).__init__()
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(5, 5))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(5))

    def forward(self,x,other_params):
        hidden = torch.matmul(self.weight,other_params) + self.bias
        out = torch.matmul(x,hidden)
        return out


class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(5, 5))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(5))
        self.other_params = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(5,5))
        self.sub_model = SubModel()

    def forward(self, x):
        hidden = self.sub_model(x,self.other_params)
        out = torch.matmul(hidden, self.weight.t()) + self.bias
        return out
```

Furthermore, I would like to confirm if this parameter `other_params` can be shared among multiple submodels? could this lead to some training errors or parameter updating error? Thank you very much for explaining the method of parameter update.

For example:

```py
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(5, 5))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(5))
        self.other_params = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(5,5))
        # self.sub_model = SubModel()
        self.sub_model_1 = SubModel()
        self.sub_model_2 = SubModel()

    def forward(self, x):
        hidden = self.sub_model_1(x,self.other_params)
        hidden = self.sub_model_2(hidden,self.other_params)
        out = torch.matmul(hidden, self.weight.t()) + self.bias
        return out
```

I have add breakpoints and observed the parameters could be updating and loss is decreased.